# android java manifest.xml wont load on phone

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

This is my manifest file
http://grab.by/uzwu (screenshot)
when I run it on the phone it does not show up with in the apps 
when I go to app manager its right there running but it wont open or display on the app drawer
any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close your activity tags too early:

```
  <activity android:name="./Splash" >
```

should be:

```
  <activity android:name="./Splash"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       etc.. more attributes and no xml comments like <!-- comments... -->    within here     
  >
```

Note the different occurence of the `>`

Eclipse shows those text that are placed wrong in a different color (black) because of this to visualize this to you that it is not parsed as attributes in the xml. You can see that in your screenshot

Comment: get rid of that `<!-- .... --> ` parts. you cannot nest them inside other xml tags. either delete them or move them to valid positions

Comment: it starts but the app still doesnt shoe up in the app drawer

Comment: put this: `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` instead `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASH" />`

Comment: thanks it starts but stops working after the splash has been played then crashes

Comment: check if there are any errors logged in the logcat, that will help you identify the cause of the crash & tell you the line in your code that caused it

Comment: somewhere in your app code (Splash.java line 27) you are trying to start an Activity with an intent action "...bubblepop.Main" but you didn't declare that activity that can handle this intent in AndroidManifest.xml. Maybe start this Activity with something like `startActivity(this, BubblePopActivity.class)` instead.

Comment: can you maybe post this java class & the complete AndroidManifest.xml as code-blocks into your question? It's sort of hard to analyse this with screenshots, because I don't see the whole thing

Comment: its hard for me to do that when i paste the code in it distorts it and cuts out allot of parts

Comment: Don't worry about that. There are many moderators around that can edit formatting problems inside your questions and will make it look better. I suggest following: Ask a new question and put both screenshot and code-blocks of your Activity & AndroidManifest files incl. Should be a new question because now you have a different problem.